# How can I edit multiple data in Firebase database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have child that's including user informations.
I need to change "FirstName" and "LastName" in the same time.
How can I set child and value?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `updateChildValues`:

```
var updates : [AnyHashable: Any] = ["your/path/firstName": firstName,
                                    "your/path/lastName": lastName]
ref.updateChildValues(updates)
```

Comment: Yeah!. I just found this too. however thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!!.
Use "updateChildValues" instead of "setValue" in "child" key.

Answer (score -1):

```
ref.child("users").child(uid).child("firstName").setValue(firstName)
ref.child("users").child(uid).child("lastName").setValue(lastName)
```

change the path to fit where your data is stored if necessary

Comment: I just found solution. It should use "updateChildValues".